# Microsoft Power Automate Condition comparing multi values

Tags: power-automate

Dears
Greetings,,

I'm trying to create a Ms flow that uses condition if  any  one of these employees numbers submit a form consider it as yes others no.
If possible get the chosen employees from the excel table
employees numbers:
1115
1114
2150
2233
3322
5555
**etc**
more than 50 employees numbers
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a Filter Array to check if the single item is part of a Employees numbers array. After that you can check if it has a match.

Belows is an example with a manual trigger to give you an idea of the approach.

[image]